# How to connect to a fixed IP address device with a different network portion than my local network?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

My Actiontec WCB3000N has a fixed IP of `192.168.99.254` (or, at least, that's what it says on the side of the device). My LAN is `192.168.68.0` and when I try to direct my browser to `192.168.99.254`, it times out. When I ping, I get "Destination Net Unreachable". I suspect the reason is that my routing table directs traffic to my gateway (router) for anything other than `192.168.68.0`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.68.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.68.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Is there a configuration change I could make to allow me to connect to `192.168.99.254`?

Comment: The documentation says "The default IP address for the WCB3000N is 192.168.99.254 when it is not connected to a router with a DHCP server. If it is connected to a router the IP address will be assigned to the WCB3000N using DHCP. If you are having issues accessing configuration page or GUI please contact Technical Support."   From:  https://actiontecsupport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000504846-How-do-I-access-the-configuration-page-or-GUI-of-the-device-   Does this help?

Comment: Yes, apologies for not reading the documentation. I looked for the devices on my router client list, but they didn't show up (initially). However, now that I look again, I can see them and use the assigned IP to access them. My goal was to disable the wireless, which I was able to do (since I simply used them to make a wired connection via MoCA). Thank you!

Comment: So I have answered your question?  I think so.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for your extender says

> The default IP address for the WCB3000N is 192.168.99.254 when it is
> not connected to a router with a DHCP server. If it is connected to a
> router the IP address will be assigned to the WCB3000N using DHCP. If
> you are having issues accessing configuration page or GUI please
> contact Technical Support.

From https://actiontecsupport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000504846-How-do-I-access-the-configuration-page-or-GUI-of-the-device-

Using this you should be able to (a) get an IP and (b) manage the device.